# Access elements outside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Basically i've got a webpage and an iframe within it which loads another page. Within that iframe page is a script. I want to access the parent document of the iframe thus gaining access to elements outside the iframe.

Which function should i use ? Is this even doable ?

**Note** Both pages are from the same domain.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the parent window by placing this within the iframe: `<base target="_parent" />`

Comment: is there no other way to get the contents of the iframe's parent without the base tag